# Show Turtle-File on html page with line brakes

Tags: javascript, html, turtle-rdf

i am trying to show a turtle file on a very simple homepage i made.

```
<p class="lead" id="testbed-meta"> 
    <script>
    $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: "/native/api/resources/turtle",
            success: function(data,status){ 
            document.getElementById("testbed-meta").innerHTML = data;       
            },
            error: function(xhl,status){
            document.getElementById("testbed-meta").innerHTML = "Error";
            },
            statusCode:{                
                201: function(){
                alert("Error");
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
```

HTML don't understand that it's turtle and makes it to one long String without line brakes and also deletes some parts. Maybe because there are some "<" and ">" that are not escaped.

Is there a nice way to show a ttl file via html and maybe javascript?

**EDIT:**
By the way, i forgot to say that i get something like this in the answer:

```
@prefix omn-federation: <http://open-multinet.info/ontology/omn-federation#> .
```

But HTML don't show the "http:/....." part. Only:

```
@prefix omn-federation: .
```

Maybe because of the "<" and ">" ?!

Answer (score 0):

try with a `pre` tag instead of `p` tag:

```
<pre class="lead" id="testbed-meta"></pre>
```

> The HTML Preformatted Text (`<pre>`) represents preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in a non-proportional font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespaces inside this element are displayed as typed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

```
<pre class="lead" id="testbed-meta"> </pre>
<script>
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "/native/api/resources/turtle",
        success: function(data,status){ 
             document.getElementById("testbed-meta").innerHTML = data.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi, '\n').replace(/</g, '&lt;'); 


        },
        error: function(xhl,status){
        document.getElementById("testbed-meta").innerHTML = "Error";
        },
        statusCode:{                
            201: function(){
            alert("Error");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

See this small snippets:

```js
data = '<br/> \@prefix omn-federation: <open-multinet.info/ontology/omn-federation#>; . <br/> \@prefix rdf: <w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>; . <br/>'
document.getElementById("testbed-meta").innerHTML = data.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi, '\n').replace(/</g, '&lt;');
```

```html
<pre id="testbed-meta"></pre>
```

Comment: Thx ben for the Info, but it didn't work. The text is just a little bit bigger. Still no line brakes.
Can i provide you any additional Infos to find the problem?

Comment: I edited my first poste, maybe it's because of the tags?

Comment: Can you copy the data you are receiving ?
`<pre>` should do the trick for the new lines (basically if your data contains  `\n` or `\r`).
For the `<`, you need to replace them. Either using jquery `.text` or with plain JS `.replace(/</g, '&lt;')`

Comment: First lines of data i receive looks like this:<br/>
\@prefix omn-federation: <http://open-multinet.info/ontology/omn-federation#> . <br/>
\@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> . <br/>
I used the .text and then then the .replace Method, but now i have "<br>" tags in my text and still no line brakes. With <pre> by the way

Comment: Oh! So you have `<br>` which should not be escaped and other tags which should be... See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your success callback:

```
$("#testbed-meta").text(data);
```

jQuery's [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method escapes all HTML for you.

Additionally, if you'd like to get new lines in your HTML, you need to replace all new line characters to HTML's `<br>` tag:

```
$("#testbed-meta").text(data).replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, "$1<br>$2");
```

Comment: I get an Error if i use your method:
[TypeError: "#testbed-meta".text is not a function].
my Script now looks like this:

success: function(data,status){ 


   ("#testbed-meta").text(data);  


   },

Comment: That's strange, because you are using jQuery in your example and `.text()` is built-in jQuery method.

Comment: Sry, i forgot the $ . Now its showing something. My Fault. Will now try to implement the line brakes

Comment: I used your second Code-Line but i get again the "TypeError: .text...replace is not a function" so i wrote it like this:

var newData = data.replace(...);
$("#testbed-meta").text(newData);

But now i have "<br>" standing in my text but still no line brakes, although i have used <pre> instead of <p>